# ordering object creation in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

There is a mystery I can't solve with angular. the creation order of component

```
//the app.html
<navigation ></navigation>
<X></X>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The router outlet is loading an element which is lazy load depending on the path.

When I refresh the page. The constructor of the lazy load component in router outlet is call Before navigation constructor or X constructor.

Is there a way to force the navigation component or X to be load & construct before the lazy load component ?

Comment: Have you tried something like `<router-outlet *ngIf="ready">`?

Comment: I had hope there would be a way to enforce it in typescript/angular instead. but that's a way

Comment: MoreOver.router-outlet is need for the component to load otherwise angular is lost. if the ng if is still to false. It's gonna break everything.

Comment: Why does the order matter for you? If there is any data dependencies that should be fix via a resolver.